# Command only works in cmd line but not in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy some file. It can already be copied by using the command line, but not in a batch file.

```
@echo off

E:

cd Testing\ihelpdesk_extraction


XCOPY Testing.csv "\\10.44.103.111\Shared_Folder\Shared_Folder\"

exit
```

My current directory is `C:\Users\Administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

Use full paths:
i.e.:

```
XCOPY "E:\Testing\ihelpdesk_extraction\Testing.csv" "\\10.44.103.111\Shared_Folder\Shared_Folder\Testing.csv"
```

Comment: sorry Luca B..still not functioning..im already use before this as you stated.

Comment: does it yelds you any specific error? (Also try turning the echo on to better debug)